# Let’s fill [lead-poisoning] full of [lead]!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

There are currently four questions tagged [lead](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lead) and five questions tagged [lead-poisoning](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lead-poisoning), one of which is tagged with both.

All of the questions tagged with lead are about lead poisoning, which means that if both tags were worth keeping, they’d all ought to have both tags, which means one of them is redundant.

I think we should get rid of the lead-poisoning tag, in case someone wants to ask a question which is about lead, but isn’t about lead poisoning.

Comment: Title inspired by [this comment](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14449/is-lead-exposure-responsible-for-the-rise-and-fall-of-violent-crime-in-the-us#comment52667_14449)

Comment: I can't imagine getting many if any questions about lead that aren't also about the health/environmental implications of lead exposure. I guess deriving from the old transmutation tales there might be some modern notable claims about lead (e.g. lead into gold), but I've yet to see one on the site.

Comment: @fredsbend not about lead, but there is one about gold: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34370/does-cow-urine-contain-gold?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a synonym from lead-poisoning -> lead.

Answer (score 6):

I agree, get rid of [lead-poisoning](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lead-poisoning). The [lead](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lead) tag can be paired with one of the health or medical tags to further specify the nature of the question. I don't think a tag specifically for the poisoning aspect is necessary.

I think we could probably make [lead-poisoning](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lead-poisoning) a synonym of [lead](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lead).